# Azure DevOps does not find my azure-pipelines.yaml file

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I've just created `~\azure-pipelines.yaml`, committed and pushed but when I go into Azure DevOps > Pipelines and add a new build, choose my repo (also Azure DevOps) then I just get the options for the classic wizard style builds.

How do I choose my YAML file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Azure DevOps Pipelines should have seen your YAML file as soon as you pushed and your build should be visible with an empty list of build history, and an Edit button in the top right where you can change the YAML contents.

You can manually add a new pipeline and choose Existing Azure Pipelines YAML file from the list, near the bottom and then type in the path to your YAML file.

Otherwise, rename your file to `.yml` extension and DevOps will automatically see it if its in the root.

Comment: deleting the old pipeline and creating a new did it for me. But that didn't answer me why it failed to find it. Also I would potentially loose all my pipeline history.